# How many ranked games must I play to be ranked?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing some ranked matches today. I got lucky and found a good AD carry to lane with me in the first match; we duo queued together a few more games and I ended up with 4 wins out of 4 matches, but I'm still Unranked with no visible points.

Is there a minimum number of points required or a minimum number of matches played before I get my status?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get placed into a League (Bronze, Silver or Gold, but not Platinum, Diamond, or  Challenger) as soon as you complete all 10 of your "placement matches".

Near the end of the 10 matches, if you keep winning, the matches will include harder opponents -- presumably, to see if you are equal to them and should be placed into Gold. If you want to start higher, you can 'duo queue' with a friend with a high rank. [..assuming that you win :) ]

Comment: since when could you play ranked at any level below 30??

Comment: @Ravekner I cut those remarks from the answer. I don't exactly remember everything correctly all the time ;)

Comment: Challenger isn't only for teams.

Comment: @Schism GHAGHH I should really be looking this up

Comment: Your MMR (or Matchmaking Rating, similar to Starcraft II's and the former ELO system in League) also has some impact on where you were placed. I won 7 of my 10 placements and got placed into Gold V, whereas a friend of mine had the same number of wins in placement and ended up Bronze III. The only discernible difference between our games is that I duo'd with people that were already ranked; some in Gold, some in Plat, which ended up matching us against opponents of the same caliber. Hence, higher rating.

Comment: @Ravekner that's some time longer ago, at the end of season two it was introduced, that you can play ranked earlier than lvl. 30. the only level 30 restriction is, as far as i know the tribunal

Comment: Based on [the link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108849/12936) that [iber gave in his answer](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ranked_game) `"A ranked game is a draft mode game type available to level 30 summoners with at least 16 champions available (excluding free week champions)."`

Comment: @vogel612 I don't know where you received your information. But unless it was at the very beginning of season 1, at the very very end of season 2, talking like the last two weeks, or at the very beginning of season 3, again only 2 weeks, I cannot ever recall players being able to play ranked games below lvl 30. This would have been a horrible idea in the first place due to the people below lvl 30 having a markedly greater disadvantage in runes/masteries the lower their level.

Comment: @Ravekner i recall it was introduced somewhen in the end of season 2 (after i just got lvl 30)  that you can now play ranked from lvl 28 or 25 (i don't really care though, cause it does not concern me)

Comment: I can kind of understand lvl 28. Any lower than that would end up resulting in too many skewed matches.

Comment: The requirement was level 20, but it was changed to 30 in 2010 with this announcement: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=175678

Answer (score 4):

You need play at least 10 ranked games to be ranked. You will be unranked again when new season starts. [Source Wiki.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ranked_game)